# Open CMake proejct in Visual Studio 2019 using command line

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, devenv

I use Visual Studio IDE to develop, VS C++ to compile, CMake to generate the project in VS and Ninja to build.

I have a script that clone a project from git server and automate several steps I need to perform before start working on it.

At the end of this script I would like to open the project in Visual Studio. Before I used to generate the VS solution instead and then use devenv with the sln file as a parameter to open it. But now that I use VS support for CMake if I use CMakeList.txt file as a parameter it only opens this file not the complete project.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your script? Please show what it currently does. Does it run CMake for you? Why can't it open the CMake-generated Visual Studio solution file after it is created?

Comment: It does not matter what my script is doing. I need a way to open a CMake project in Visual Studio using a command-line. This works: devenv solution.sln (where solution.sln is a Visual Studio solution) but this devenv CMakeList.txt (where CMakeList.txt is the CMake file in the root of the project) does open the file in Visual Studio but does not load the whole project. I need to load a CMake project in visual studio from command line to be able to load it from my script or a batch file.

Comment: So, to rephrase my earlier question, does this work: `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && devenv solution.sln` ?

Comment: No, I don't use visual studio solutions anymore. I only use the IDE and the compiler but I build using Ninja. To open the project from the IDE you go to File -> Open -> CMake... and select the CMakeList.txt file from the root folder of the project. But doing that from command-line is only opening the file in the editor, not loading the project. Probably there is no way to do it as the support for CMake is getting better but still far from the support for Microsoft solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your project's root CMakeLists.txt is located in `C:\project\CMakeLists.txt` you can call

```
devenv "C:\project"
```

without the CMakeLists.txt.

Note that currently there seems to be a bug in Visual Studio 16.7 that when opening a directory, all the views (e.g. solution explorer) are hidden by default. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1140297/visual-studio-is-forgetting-docked-viewwindow-layo.html)